# Type guard for union type (Function | RegExp) does not work

Tags: typescript

This code seems to cause a compile error (checked with TypeScript 1.6.2):

```
var a: ((input: any) => boolean) | string | RegExp = "foobar";
if (typeof a === 'function') {
    a(100); // compile error here
}
```

The compiler says `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

I entered this in the TS Playground and found that `a` has a type `((input: any) => boolean) | RegExp` inside the if-clause, which was not what I expected. Of course `typeof /abc/` returns `'object'`, so I believe `a` should never be a regular expression in the if-clause.

I guess this is somehow related to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4612) and "aggressive subtype reduction", but I'm not sure about that.

Explicit type assertion (`(<Function>a)(100)`) did not solve my problem. Is there a quick workaround?

**EDIT**: Updated the question because it turned out that this was not a 1.6-specific issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Type guards on functions using `typeof` work in TS 2.0+. This should no longer be an issue.

So as pointed out in the issue below, the current supported way is to use `instanceof`...

```
var a: ((input: any) => boolean) | string | RegExp = "foobar";

if (a instanceof Function) {
    a(100); // ok
}
```

However, there's some new discussion in [#4868](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4868) about supporting using `typeof`.

---

**Original Answer**

What you're saying does seem like a bug to me.

For now, you could use a user defined type guard:

```
function isFunction(obj: any) : obj is Function {
    return typeof obj === "function";
}

if (isFunction(a)) {
    a(10);
}
```

Or assert to the any type and then assert to the type of the function:

```
(a as any as (input: any) => boolean)(100);
```

I've opened issue [#4850](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4850) to inquire about this.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll go with the double type assertion for the time being. (But I wonder why it works... is that a well-known technique described elsewhere?)

Comment: @naruto it's a new feature in 1.6. I'm not sure why it works and not the regular type guard. We'll see what they say in the issue.